# how to discard nodes has same values as earlier nodes in xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

my xml is as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="document-library-filter.xsl"?>
<xml total="14">
    <document>
        
        <file_type><![CDATA[application/pdf]]></file_type>
        <file_size><![CDATA[4420 KB]]></file_size>
        <document_group><![CDATA[LED Systems 1]]></document_group>
        
    </document>
    <document>
        
        <file_type><![CDATA[application/pdf]]></file_type>
        <file_size><![CDATA[4420 KB]]></file_size>
        <document_group><![CDATA[LED Systems 1]]></document_group>
        
</xml>
```

it contains multiple document node. and each document node has file type node. value is pdf for all document nodes.
i want to write out single file type node. and discard other nodes as they has same values.
to do that i try to write out following xslt. but it writes out all the nodes.

following is the xslt:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <hr class="grid-hr inner-grid"/>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>%%filter-file-types%%:</legend>
        <ul class="itembrowser-filter">
            <xsl:for-each select="xml/document">
                <xsl:if test="file_type">
                    <xsl:variable name="file_type">
                        <xsl:value-of select="file_type"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="file_type_Value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($file_type,'/')"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" 
                                   class="input-big-checkbox" 
                                   name="filetype-filter" 
                                   value="{$file_type}"/>
                            <span class="label">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="$file_type_Value"/>
                            </span>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <hr class="grid-hr inner-grid"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i need some way to compare both the node values and if they are same then it will write out only once.

my expected output is:

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>%%filter-file-types%%:</legend>
<ul class="itembrowser-filter">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" 
                   class="input-big-checkbox" 
                   name="filetype-filter" 
                   value="application/pdf"/>
            <span class="label">
                <xsl:copy-of select="pdf"/>
            </span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
```

i am not able to achieve this. please help me out.

Comment: This is a grouping question. Read up on [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) and browse the numerous examples already posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet iterates through all `document` elements and will therefore output a `fieldset` for each.

This template produces the expected output:

```
<xsl:template match="//file_type[not(.=preceding::file_type)]">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>%%filter-file-types%%:</legend>
    <ul class="itembrowser-filter">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" class="input-big-checkbox" name="filetype-filter" value="{.}"/>
          <span class="label">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'/')"/>
          </span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</xsl:template>
```

The template matches the first `file_type` element of all `file_type` elements with the same value.